# Restrict html file access in wordpress based on logged in users

Tags: html, wordpress, restrict

We have html files in the folder in WordPress application. we want to restrict html files based wordpress user login, how can we restrict html file access?

The htaccess password mechanism is not good enough because user already logged into WordPress again entering credentials in a popup is unwanted.

Any pointers to implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution i used for protected files in Wordpress. The files resided in a specific folder, access was denied for all users in that folder via .htaccess. access-control purely by wordpress user status.

serve.php :

```
<?php 
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: html');
header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
//this will enable the basic functionality to check for user status
$wpload=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
Include_once($wpload);
$loggedin= is_user_logged_in();
//here you can also do more extensive checks. eg: each user has only access to his own folder or files
if(!$loggedin) exit;

$file= sanitize_text_field($_GET['file']);
$file= realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../uploads/myplugin/').'/'.$file;

ob_end_clean();
readfile($file);
?>
```

The link to get the file would then look something like this:

```
https://mydomain/serve.php?file=my-sample.html
```

This works very well. One disadvantage is, that browser-caching is not working with this method and on serverside the output is also slower. It shouldn't be a problem with html files. i used it to show images, added maybe 500ms delay.

so, basically, serve.php is a standalone-file that loads the basic wordpress files and examines a parameter passed in the querystring.